# android application connections with https on 8060 port blocked by antivirus

Tags: android, ssl, server, port, antivirus

We have an android application that uses retrofit v2 to make the connection with our server, on the other hand, we configured our server with https with a valid SSL on 8060 port, and use this port for making the connection between API server and Android application, but we have a big problem, antivirus applications block connection of the app with the server! we don't know why this is happening! do you have any idea or solution for solving it?

Comment: tell the user to permit your app to make the connection in the antivirus configuration; are you asking how to circumvent some antivirus?

Comment: @kamyarhaqqani I wanna know why this is happening and how can I solve it :)

Comment: Is the used SSL certificate a self-signed one or a trusted from Let's Encrypt or another common CA? Do you use cert pinning in your app?